# What is an external id and where we can use it in Odoo?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-view

If anyone knows what an external id is, and what are its uses, I will be thankful.

I didn't find resources about that on the web.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: But from where do you have the matter for the question to ask?

Answer (score 8):

An *External ID*, also known as an *XML Id*, is an identifier for a data record. Odoo uses a base Model, `ir.model.data`, to map identifiers with the corresponding actual database IDs.

Whenever an External Id is referenced by another data record, or by some server-side Python code, `ir.model.data` allows to translate that string identifier into the specific record ID used for it in this particular database.

Comment: What about uniqueness of the external id? Should external id be unique globally or only per module? Are there any conventions about creating external ids in your own modules?

Comment: They must be unique inside a model. The full identifier `<module>.<external_id>` is then globally unique. For name conventions the easiest is to have a look at what is done in the official modules.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

**`get_external_id`**

is kinda crap and may not return an id: it just gets a random existing xid but won't generate one if there is no xid currently associated with the record. And operating with xids isn't exactly fun in RPC.

**Example:**

```
# backwards compatibility
get_xml_id = get_external_id
_get_xml_ids = _get_external_ids
```

Comment: I need explanation for external id ,because I do not have a clear idea about this

Answer (score 0):

By **debug mode** then go the the **form** of the recod then **view metadata** from the **Debug icon** in the top left.
You can find it in the database by  `YOUR_MODEL` and `ID` in the request:

```
select module,name
from ir_model_data
where model = 'YOUR_MODEL' and res_id=ID
```